# Background not changing to red

Tags: jquery

http://removed.com/jquery/#
First time playing with jQuery, and kind of stuck already. I'm expecting the background to change to red on hover, but it's not for some reason. Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the jQuery code for `div.sidenavOff` inside the `ready` defintion, like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(event){
            alert("Thanks for visiting!");
        });
        $("div.sidenavOff").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass("sidenavOver");
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass("sidenavOff");       
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This worked! Does every jQuery thing have to be in the ready function?

Comment: If you are going to work with the DOM or you have your scripts in the head.  You either need to run it in $(document).ready() or move your script to the bottom of the page where it can be run after the DOM has been loaded onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the calls to .mouseover and .mouseout in your `$(document).ready(function() {...` block. As you have it, when the selector `$("div.sidenavOff")` is called, those elements don't exist yet, and no handlers are attached. Moving them into document.ready will call them after the elements have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do smth like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.sidenavOff").mouseover(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("sidenavOver").toggleClass("sidenavOff",true);
    }
   )
 }
)
```

it has the same functionality as Jonathan's example, but it's less code to write:)